# What does Prism actually offer the developer? And is it worth it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

In simple, practical terms, what does Prism offer, and is it worth it? My experience of MS's application development frameworks - Enterprise Library for example - is that they're generally overly complex, heavyweight, and force you to couple your application to components that don't offer a huge amount and can't easily be switched out later.

What are peoples' opinions and experiences of using Prism in the real world?

Comment: PRISM is an exciting new 32-bit processor from DEC... oh, wait, wrong decade.

Comment: A good read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205752.aspx

Comment: I have created a new question related to this as I also want to decide on whether to learn PRISM or not. I have tried to make it  answerable and  hope that it won't get closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251821/custom-mvvm-implementation-vs-prism

Answer (score -1):

Yes PRISM is good as it gives the application and independence being able to change front end either in wpf or silverlight without the change of backend but for this independence developement team needs a huge amount of time and in practical business oriented environment you don't get that much of time. But if time is in your side then you can develop using PRISM as application will be really flexible.